# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while starting Spring application on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am getting this very strange error when i try to run the project on Tomcat 8:

> INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
>   . INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jun 29 10:59:34 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
>   . INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com...]
>
> ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster

Full stack trace bellow:

> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;.
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8099"]
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFO: Initialization processed in 823 ms
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:04 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.siemens.ott.RestServiceWebAppIntializer@5fb6fe5e]
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   .11:40:04.745 INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
>   .11:40:04.760 INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jun 29 11:40:04 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
>   .11:40:04.848 INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.ott.BusinessBeans] 
>   .11:40:05.192 ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
>       at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.setBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:84) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:60) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:667) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:471) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
>   lip 29, 2015 11:40:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
>       at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.setBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:667)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:471)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My first thought was that there are some errors in Spring version but i cannot find anything. This is pretty much same project setup i have used couple of times, with the only difference that this is java 8 project.

Project is Dynamic Web Module 3.1.

Bellow are dependencies from the .pom file, i don't see any collisions in the versions.

Kindly help if somebody encountered this before.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

mvn dependecy tree:

> C:\Users\Z003DP9F\java-8 workspace\workspace\vmgw>mvn dependency:tree
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building vmgw 1.0
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 has been relocated to javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ vmgw ---
>   [WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 has been relocated to javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1
>   [INFO] com.siemens.ott:vmgw:war:1.0
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.5:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
>   [INFO] +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
>   [INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
>   [INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
>   [INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
>   [INFO] |  - javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
>   [INFO] |  - org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
>   [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
>   [INFO] |  - commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
>   [INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
>   [INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
>   [INFO] - org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.1.Final:compile
>   [INFO]    +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
>   [INFO]    - com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Please post the full stack trace instead of a snippet and add the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: i am downloading plugins for mvn dependency:tree, will post this in a moment. Please let me know if i can add some additional information for clarity.

Comment: Just put the output. At least a thing I noticed you want to specify `<scope>test</scope>` to the `spring-ws-test` and `spring-test` dependencies, you don't want those in your app they are only needed for testing.

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you are mixing versions (4.1.6 and 4.0.9). I strongly suggest the use of either the spring framework bom or (better) the spring io platform. Saves you figuring out which versions of frameworks work together.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have suggestion which you could turn into answer, how do i resolve those collisions in simplest way possible ?

Comment: by adding them in your pom, but that isn't the best... And please don't add the output as images but as text with formatting tags, images become unreadable!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing different versions of Spring which are incompatible. Regardless you should never mix jars from different versions of any framework (Spring, Hibernate, JSF etc.) as that is trouble bound to happen.

The best way is to simply use the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/).

Add the following to your pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then remove the versions in your pom as the versions are now being managed by the `platform-bom`, you should now have versions that work together and no more conflicting versions. For a list of managed version check this [appendix](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it it pick up new versions as they are released, and if so, can i prevent this plugin from doing it ?

Comment: No as you are using a specific bom version, to update versions you either have to declare them yourself explicitly or update the bom (if a new version is out). You could also use it as a parent pom instead of `dependencyManagement` one. Advantage of this is that you can use `<properties>` to specify versions. For instance if you want another Spring Versions add `<spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>` would give you that version, but only if you use it as a parent.